# Using map in JSX producing undefined items

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to generate `<Audio>` components with `map`:

```
import React, { useState, useRef, createRef } from 'react';

const audios = [{ src: '/fire.mp3' }, { src: '/crickets.mp3' }];

function Audio({ audioRef }) {
  const { src, ref } = audioRef;

  function handleVolumeChange(value) {
    ref.current.volume = value / 100;
  }

  return (
    <audio ref={ref} loop>
      <source src={src} type="audio/mpeg" /> Your browser does not support the
      audio element.
    </audio>
    // `handleVolumeChange` is used here
  );
}

export const App = ({ name }) => {
  const audioRefs = useRef(
    audios.map((audio) => ({
      ...audio,
      ref: createRef(),
    }))
  );
    
  return (
    <>
      {audioRefs.current.map((audioRef, index) => (
        <Audio key={audioRef.src} audio={audioRef} />
      ))}
    </>
  );
};
```

However, I'm getting this error:

> Cannot destructure property 'src' of 'audioRef' as it is undefined.

Why is `audioRef` undefined when `audioRefs` is an array?

```
[{…}, {…}]
  0: Object
    ref: Object
    src: "/fire.mp3"
    <prototype>: Object
  1: Object
    ref: Object
    src: "/crickets.mp3"
    <prototype>: Object
```

Working code on [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-3bznfa?file=src%2FApp.tsx).

Note: I need the ref to control the volume of the `<audio>` element.

Comment: Why do you need a ref for this?

Comment: @0stone0 To control the volume of the `<audio>` element. I updated my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to use [`React.forwardRef()`](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html) in `<Audio />` to be able to forward to `<audio>`.

---

Small demo using 2 test `mp3`'s from https://onlinetestcase.com/mp3-file/.

Press the button to toggle the volume between the default `1.0` and `0.2`.

```js
const { useState, useRef, createRef, forwardRef } = React;

const Audio = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {

    const handleVolumeChange = () => {
        ref.current.volume = (ref.current.volume === 1 )
            ? 0.2 
            : 1.0;
    }
    
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <audio ref={ref} loop={true} controls={true}>
                <source src={props.src} type="audio/mpeg" /> 
            </audio>
            <button onClick={handleVolumeChange}>Toggle volume</button>
            <br />
        </React.Fragment>
    );
});

const App = ({ name }) => {
    const audios = [
        { src: 'https://onlinetestcase.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/06/100-KB-MP3.mp3' }, 
        { src: 'https://onlinetestcase.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/06/500-KB-MP3.mp3' }
    ];

    const audioRefs = useRef(
        audios.map((audio) => ({
            ...audio,
            ref: createRef(),
        }))
    );

    return audioRefs.current.map((audioRef, index) => {
        return <Audio key={audioRef.src} {...audioRef} />;
    })
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("react"));
```

```css
html, body, #react { height: 100vh; width: 100vw; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

---

A quote from the [*Accessing another component's DOM nodes*](https://react.dev/learn/manipulating-the-dom-with-refs#accessing-another-components-dom-nodes) page:

> [...]
>
> > **Warning**: Function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access this ref will fail. Did you mean to use React.forwardRef()?
>
> This happens because by default React does not let a component access the DOM nodes of other components. Not even for its own children! This is intentional. Refs are an escape hatch that should be used sparingly. Manually manipulating another component’s DOM nodes makes your code even more fragile.
>
> Instead, components that want to expose their DOM nodes have to opt in to that behavior. A component can specify that it “forwards” its ref to one of its children. Here’s how `MyInput` can use the `forwardRef` API:
>
> ```
> const MyInput = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
>     return <input {...props} ref={ref} />;
> });
> ```
>
> [...]

Comment: Thanks for the working example. This is the first time I hear about `forwardRef`. Why is that my code doesn't work without it?

Comment: I'm not quite sure *why* it needs `forwardRef`, just this is the way I've learned it ;) The [`forwardRef` React.Dev page](https://react.dev/reference/react/forwardRef) does provide some additional info. Hope that helps. (I;ll search for a more detailed explanation later on if I've got some more time) I've added a quick quote from [this section](https://react.dev/learn/manipulating-the-dom-with-refs#accessing-another-components-dom-nodes).

Answer (score 1):

Presumably this is the line producing the error?:

```
const { src, ref } = audioRef;
```

In which case `audioRef` is a prop on the `Audio` component here:

```
function Audio({ audioRef }) {
```

Where do you use that `Audio` component?  Here:

```
<Audio key={audioRef.src} audio={audioRef} />
```

As you can see, you're not passing a prop called `audioRef`.  You're passing a prop called `audio` (and a `key`).

The prop names need to match.

Either change the expected prop name to match what's being passed:

```
function Audio({ audio }) {
```

**Or** change what's being passed to match what's expected:

```
<Audio key={audioRef.src} audioRef={audioRef} />
```